# Why is code in Net::SSL dereferencing typeglobs where I can't see the need?

Tags: perl, typeglob

`Net::SSL` is part of Crypt::SSLeay. While working on a bug report today, I was distracted by how many times the poor old `*` made an appearance.

For example, consider `Net::SSL::configure`:

```
*$self->{ssl_version} = $ssl_version;
*$self->{ssl_debug} = $ssl_debug;
*$self->{ssl_arg} = $arg;
*$self->{ssl_peer_addr} = $arg->{PeerAddr};
*$self->{ssl_peer_port} = $arg->{PeerPort};
```

Maybe it's because I am not that familiar with pre 5.8 Perl, but I just can't pinpoint whether there is a significant reason for using `*` on the LHS. Wouldn't just `*$self->{ssl_peer_port} = $arg->{PeerPort};` be sufficient? Or, is there something deep going on here (e.g. `local $_` versus `local *_`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have the module installed, so can’t check easily enough, but I presume that it’s because the object is a globref; that is, a reference to a blessed typeglob.

There’s no aliasing going on here.  When you write

```
 *$self->{ssl_debug} = $ssl_debug;
```

It first derefs the globref back to a full typeglob. It then grabs just the hashref aspect of the typeglob and proceeds to dereference that.

This isn’t a pre- or post-5.8 thing.

What was it you were thinking it was doing?

Comment: I got confused and thought `$self->{ssl_debug}` was being treated as a typeglob. Thanks for the answer. The reason I brought the pre-5.6 is because I don't know what I don't know ;-)

Comment: @SinanÜnür Think of it as a matter of precedence, in which prefix dereferencers go first before postfix ones. Or thinking of `->` as imposing a `${...}` around its lefthand side.  When in C you read `*argv[0]` that’s really `*(argv[0])`, but in Perl, `$$aref[0]` is `${$aref}[0]` not `${$aref[0]}`. The other prefix dereffers, including `*`, also go first. So your expression was `${ *$self }{ssl_debug}` — which might perhaps have made things worse if you had chanced upon it in the wild. :)

Answer (score 1):

tchrist is (as always) on the right track. You can play around with `IO::Socket` and see what you can and can't do with references to blessed typeglobs.

```
use IO::Socket;
$foo = IO::Socket->new;

print $foo;                      # IO::Socket=GLOB(0x20467b18)
print *$foo;                     # *Symbol::GEN0
print ref($foo);                 # IO::Socket
print ref(*$foo);                # ""

*$foo->{key} = value;            # ok
$$foo->{key} = value;            # ok
$foo->{key} = value;             # Not a HASH reference at ...
```